# how to get webapck 2 inclusion path

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-2

After updating local grunt I got these errors when building the app with webpack2:

> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   app/common/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.d.ts:6:25 
>       TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   app/common/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.d.ts:14:32 
>       TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   app/common/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.d.ts:15:78 
>       TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   app/common/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.d.ts:23:39 
>       TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
>          [0] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./app/index.html 1.21 kB {0} [built]

The only place where this conv-lite can be found in the app is some grunt lib. And I hope it's not referenced anywhere in the app code. So the question if there is any way to find the path webpack wandered until failing to find some dependency? Something like  mvn dependency:tree?

ps: the ERROR was fixed by excluding unnecessary pathes from tsconfig but answers to the question are still highly appreciated.

Comment: Webpack will process node_modules by default unless you exclude like that. It is just the way it works. Common with Babel etc.

Comment: yeah, but it should pick up only the files which are referenced, that is imported, from others up to entry point, should it?

Comment: References can have references too. It's not just about the entries. You should check webpack stats against the analyse tool to tell why those specific files are brought to the project.